# shadcnui accordion in tailwind css grid system scales not as expected

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I have a next js application that renders a couple of shadcn ui accordions in a tailwind css grid system.
The accordions have to be sorted vertically and in an alphabetical order.

The section of interest starts after this headline:
NOVOTEC: AUSBAU- UND SANIERUNGSMANAGEMENT - UNSERE HAUPTLEISTUNGEN

By applying these classes

`grid md:grid-cols-4 items-center gap-4`

the design looks good by the alphabetically is horizontal. [correct design, wrong order](https://novotec-4mmn9zhru-olgoetz.vercel.app/services)

By applying these classes

`grid md:grid-cols-4 md:grid-flow-col md:grid-rows-5 items-center gap-4`

the design/rows expand too much when clicking on the accordion: [correct order, design crashes](https://novotec-mjld6ra87-olgoetz.vercel.app/services)